# How to make JavaScript break into IE built-in debugger (F12) rather than Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, ie-developer-tools, javascript-debugger

I often use this to debug JavaScript in IE ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTwsh/)):

```
if (confirm("Debug from here?"))
    debugger;
```

If I choose "yes", I see the prompt to start Visual Studio just-in-time debugger, which I proceed with to debug the script in Visual Studio.

Now I want to use IE built-in debugger instead of Visual Studio. I use this workaround:

```
if (confirm("Debug from here?"))
    throw "debug";
```

It works, but I have to check "Continue after exception" in IE built-in debugger every time I hit `throw`. Also, `throw` is different from `debugger` (which just continues execution if debugging is disabled in IE options).

*Is there a way to make [debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0bwt76sk%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) keyword to break into into IE built-in debugger (F12) rather than Visual Studio debugger?*

Setting breakpoints in IE F12 tools, then refreshing the page with F5 is not an option, because the page is a postback.

**EDITED.** Chrome browser actually gives me the desired behavior. To see what I mean, open Chrome, hit F12 to open Dev tools, then navigate to http://jsfiddle.net/jTwsh. Click [OK] upon `confirm` and you should get into debugger right on the `debugger` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest to disable the Just-In-Time debugger for Script; if you do not want to use it for.

See the below reference on how to enable/disable JIT Debugger:

[Enable/Disable Just-In-Time Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I am using IE8, there i need to start the script debugging by pressing 'Start Debugging' button or F5 under 'Script' tab in Developer Tools.

See the attached screenshot:

[image: Developer Tools Screenshot]

Comment: If I disable it (or if I don't have Visual Studio installed at all), then using `debugger` in JavaScript simply does nothing and gets ignored. However, I want it to do what it's there for: break into IE F12 debugger. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: yes, you need to open the Developer Tools by pressing F12 and start debugging session.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Win8 64-bit, IE10, VS 2012, script debugging is enabled in IE options, JIT script debugging is disabled in VS option. I open a new IE window, navigate it to `about:blank` first to enable F12 tools, hit F12 to open F12 tools. Then I navigate to http://jsfiddle.net/jTwsh and `debugger` doesn't stop. Can anyone else confirm it actually works the way @AhsanShah has described it?

Comment: It actually works for IE10 too. They key point is to click [Start Debugger] button in F12 toolbar *before* navigating to the page. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the website in debug. It is possible to run website in 'normal' runtime:

Right-Click on any page => View in browser

or ctrl+f5

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Could you clarify? I want to set a break-point, that's what `debugger` keyword does. I want my script to run normally until it hits that break point, and then I want to have any option to debug.

Comment: If you hit the breakpoint while you're not in debug mode in visual studio, IE debugger should be used.

Comment: No, you hit Visual Studio debugger with `debugger`. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTwsh/) on a PC with Visual Studio installed. Make sure you have *Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)* option unchecked in IE Advanced Options. You should see Visual Studio JIT Debugger prompt if you click [OK].